# Get Multiple records and show on html using jQuery ajax with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on web application in which I am trying to get 'poster' and 'message' from database and want to show result on html page, but I am able to get only 'poster' or 'message'. I want to fetch them both and show them both on html page.

I am using ajax for this purpose. here is the code below

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>DoIt</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
    #poster {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    #bgwhite {
        background-color: white;
    }

    #bgblack {
        background-color: #FCFFF0;
    }

    #box-mar {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #E9E9E9">


<div class="container-fluid" id="bgwhite">

    <div class="page-header text-center ">
        <h1>DoIt</h1>
    </div>

</div>



<div class="container " id="box-mar">

    <div class=" row ">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"  id="bgwhite">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h4 class="page-header " id="poster">
                        Umair
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="bgblack">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <p id="message">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and   typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
<script src="server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('doitdb');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infotable");

echo (mysql_num_rows($query)!==0) ? mysql_result($query,0,'message'  ):
'No Record Found';
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post('api/getdata.php', function(data) {
    $('#poster').text(data.poster);
    $('#message').text(data);
});
});
```

Comment: you need to get `HTML` or `json` from your PHP script

Comment: Please post only the code relevant to this question. For example, leave out all the CSS, as it is completely irrelevant to your question and makes it hard to read.

Comment: ok @travelboy , I will, I am new to stackoverflow and will learn rules soon